# Android Studio Test Report/Results Not Found

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.3

I followed the instructions here: https://developer.android.com/studio/test/index.html. I added this block to the Android block in the app-module gradle file:

```
testOptions {
// Changes the directory where Gradle saves test reports. By default, Gradle saves test reports
// in the path_to_your_project/module_name/build/outputs/reports/ directory.
// '$rootDir' sets the path relative to the root directory of the current project.
reportDir "$rootDir/test-reports"
// Changes the directory where Gradle saves test results. By default, Gradle saves test results
// in the path_to_your_project/module_name/build/outputs/test-results/ directory.
// '$rootDir' sets the path relative to the root directory of the current project.
resultsDir "$rootDir/test-results"
```

}

Yet, I couldn't find any test results/report in my project folder (I searched the whole folder and found nothing.

I am running Android test (not unit tests). The doc says that this block works for all types of tests, so... why it's not working?

Comment: Any luck with this? I have the same problem. I feel this is very basic and shouldn't be so difficult to get working.

Comment: any solution ? Same here.